# Twitter API: get newly created accounts

Tags: twitter, twitter-streaming-api, twitter-rest-api, twitter-search

I'm looking for a way to fetch the usernames of the most recently created accounts on Twitter, or alternatively search for accounts, filtered by join date.

There doesn't seem to be a built-in way of doing this in the Twitter API. Can anyone suggest an alternative method, or a way of using the API in a way that would achieve this?

I'm aiming to carry out similar research to [this study](http://www.adweek.com/socialtimes/twitter-username-length/467772), but I've only managed to estimate the average length of *active accounts* (by sampling live tweets via the Streaming API), as opposed to *new accounts*.

Many thanks, in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API which provides this data.

Furthermore, Twitter now uses [non-sequential 64 bit IDs](https://twittercommunity.com/t/migration-of-twitter-core-entities-to-64-bit-ids/56881) - so you can't just create a new user and increment their ID number.